# ngx-bootstrap modal - access data passed into modal via bsModalRef.content

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal, ngx-bootstrap

I am using angular 4 and ngx-bootstrap to open modals.  All is working well, and I implement modals via a component.  I can also pass data into the modal via the `content` property of the `bsModalRef`.  Like so:

```
this.bsModalRef = this.modalService.open(MyComponent);
this.bsModalRef.content.somedata = [...some array of products];
```

This all works great, and my modal can then access a property called `somedata`.  Fantastic.  The issue that I'm having is that I want to perform some calculation on `somedata`.  Assume `somedata` were a list of products with an amount, and I want the modal to reduce the amount down to a single value.  How do I know when that data is available in the modal class?  I can use a `setTimeout` hack, which works, but makes me feel icky inside.  Is there some kind of lifeCycle hook like `ngOnChanges` that `ngx-bootstrap` implements so I can know when a data property gets set, and further, when it changes?

Comment: Hi Greg, I am trying to pass data to ngx-bootstrap modal using the method you tried above but it didn't work for me. Can you tell me the ngx-bootstrap version?

Answer (score 5):

You can implement setter, or method

```
public set somedata(val) {
    // here you process data
}
```

Keep in mind that this.bsModalRef.content consists all the public members of the dialog component (in your case MyComponent).

Answer (score 3):

A better way is to use `initialState` and pass what you need

```
this.bsModalRef = this.modalService.open(MyComponent, {
 initialState: {
     products: [...some array of products]
 }
});
```

Make sure that you have a `products` array in `MyComponent`

```
export MyComponent {
    public products: any[];
}
```

@Edit: As for version 2.0.3 this way is **not** working and should not be used (even though it is referred in documentation). Please, refer to  [this issue](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues/2354) until further noticed.

Comment: If you use Modal Options and put the array in initialState instead of products then this solution will work.

Answer (score 0):

on Parent component

```
import { Modal, BSModalContext } from 'ngx-modialog/plugins/bootstrap';
import { overlayConfigFactory } from 'ngx-modialog';

var dataObject = {data1: "ba vbal", data2 :"bla bla"};
this.modal.open(urmodalCpmponent, overlayConfigFactory({data: dataObject}, BSModalContext))
```

on Modal Component

```
import { DialogRef } from 'ngx-modialog';

constructor(public dialogRef: DialogRef){
let context:any = dialogRef.context;
this.detail = context.data'
}
```